# Google appinventor - what to do with barcode?

Tags: app-inventor

Trying to create a hello world android app with app inventor, and there's an option to get the barcode.  I got it, now, what the heck do I do with it?  what's the point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a QR code, which encodes the URL of the app you've just made. That way you can download and install it.

See here for how to use it: http://sites.google.com/site/appinventorhelp/getting-started/first-app

Answer (score 0):

You can open a barcode reader app on an Android device and point the camera at the barcode on your screen.  I use "Barcode Scanner" but there are other options too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard answer given on the App Inventor forums

http://www.tair.info/faq/troubleshooting/graybutton#TOC-barcode